# Create input with type number in alert - Ionic

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

**is there a way to create input with type number in alert (AlertController)**

I try to write this but the input is working with type text, no number

```
const alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
  title: 'add Ingredient',
  inputs: [
    {
      name: 'name',
      placeholder: 'name'
    },
    {
      name: 'amount',
      placeholder: 'amount',
      type: 'number' // here the error
    }
  ],
  buttons: [
    {
      text: 'Cancel',
      role: 'cancel'
    }
  ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code on my end and its working once you add the present() in.

So it would look like this:

```
const alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
  title: 'add Ingredient',
  inputs: [
    {
      name: 'name',
      placeholder: 'name'
    },
    {
      name: 'amount',
      placeholder: 'amount',
      type: 'number' // here the error
    }
  ],
  buttons: [
    {
      text: 'Cancel',
      role: 'cancel'
    }
  ]
});

alert.present();
```

Once I add it in I can see the alert and the input is limited to numbers. The number keypad should be shown on mobile devices too.

The Ionic docs cover this in more detail [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/alert/AlertController/#alert-inputs).